# Is it possible to mix dynamic and static types in a setting such as System F or CoC?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-systems

I have a quite big codebase of untyped λ-terms. I think it could be fun trying to this codebase to the Calculus of Constructions, but I'd not like to implement everything from scratch. Instead, I'd like the type system to accept my untyped terms. I'd slowly add type annotations in a progressive manner.

My idea is to extend CoC with a "unknown" type annotation, `?`, that would always typecheck, but I'm not sure that would work. Is there any known, principled way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Some random thoughts -- Won't any actual use of such untyped term produce `?` as a type? Subject reduction can no longer preserve types, it has to account for types possibly becoming `?` at each beta reduction. Also, adding types later on is not just a matter of adding annotations, but inserting lambdas and applications for types (e.g. identity is a binary function in CoC). In Coq/Agda you may add an (inconsistent) axiom `coerce : forall a: Type, ? -> a` to force type checking, but reduction will no longer be possible.